# IE9: do not track: enable and disable

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I tried googling for how to enable and disable "do not track" in IE9 but could not find anything.  I could only find "press releases".

Please let me know the step-by-step on how to enable and disable "do not track" in IE9.

I will then verify the results using the "fiddler http protocol analyzer".

NOTE: In FF4, it is so easy to enable and disable "do not track":

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/how-do-i-stop-websites-tracking-me?s=do+not+track&as=s

Thanks.

Comment: Flagged for possible cross posting to super-user

Comment: sorry, uSlackr. I am a nube. I found superuser after posting to serverfault and was thinking that superuser might be the better place to post.

Comment: No sweat.  we all live & learn.  Hope the answer help.  Don't forget to accept an answer when you get one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this from [here](http://www.mercurynews.com/troy-wolverton/ci_17796776?nclick_check=1)

1. Click on the settings button in the upper-right corner of the browser window (it looks like a gear).
2. Click on or mouse over "Safety." This will bring up a submenu.
3. Click on "Tracking Protection." This will bring up the "Manage Add-ons" dialogue box.
4. Make sure "Tracking Protection" is selected under the list of "Add-on Types." Then click on "Your Personalized List."
5. Click the "Enable" button in the lower-right hand corner of the dialogue box.
   Note: This does something similar to turning on the "Do Not Track" feature in Firefox, although Internet Explorer will also start automatically creating a list of blocked operators by monitoring the third-party content served up by the sites you visit. Rather than waiting to generate a list, users can simply subscribe to a pre-existing one. To subscribe to one such list:
6. Open up a new browser window.
7. Go to https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/
8. Scroll down to the box that says "EasyPrivacy Tracking Protection List"
9. Click on the link to "Add EasyPrivacy Tracking Protection list to Internet Explorer 9." This will bring up the "Tracking Protection" dialogue box.
10. Click on "Add List."

Comment: Thanks uSlackr. I like the detailed response.  I just then found this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Tracking-Protection-and-ActiveX-Filtering . I like your details better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick a TPL (Tracking Protection List) like the [one found here](http://www.privacychoice.org/trackerblock/ie9).; once that is enabled DNT is automatically enabled in IE9+.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did not realize i needed to also go to a "3rd party site" like you point out. I then found this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Tracking-Protection-and-ActiveX-Filtering . As an aside, ff4 just seems simpler :  Just enable/disable "Tell websites I do not want to be tracked", done. Not sure what the IE9 implementation buys me.

Comment: IMHO the IE9 way is trying to combine something like Ad Block Plus (who's TPL you can actually use in IE9) with the DNT header. IE9 has no built in ad blocking system (like Chrome does) and no popular add-in to do it (like ABP for FF). I would imagine IE9 sends information on what TPL you're using back to MS too, so they can sell that information to advertising networks (just a guess based on previous experience).